# How to allow wordpress domain to use login from another sub domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

My case is

Wordpress URL: http://example.com

Laravel URL: http://test.example.com

I am using WordPress site for managing content and memberships and it is running successfully at: http:example.com

Now, I have created Laravel admin area on Sub-Domain i.e. http://test.example.com and each user will have their own Sub-Domain URL to login into their personal admin area and it is also working fine.

I have registered users on both WordPress and Laravel database and independently they works fine.

Issue what i am getting is, when I login from Sub-Domain, then I want to allow users to login in WordPress automatically to manage their memberships. But WordPress is not allowing me to login from Laravel Sub-Domain.

Please help me!

Here is the code which i used in my AuthCrontroller.php

```
$login_data = array();

$login_data['user_login'] = $req->email;  

$login_data['user_password'] = $req->password;  

$login_data['remember'] = true;  

$user_verify = wp_signon( $login_data, false );  

wp_set_current_user($user_verify->ID);  

wp_set_auth_cookie($user_verify->ID);  

$cur = wp_get_current_user();  

return redirect('dashboard');
```

and it was working fine when my wordpress site was [example.com] 
and Laravel site was [example.com/laravel]

Also, if I print variable $cur variable in Laravel AuthCrontroller.php then it shows that user is logged in and I can see WordPress user data. But when I try to fetch other data then it is not allowing me. Also when I move to WordPress site then it seems that user is not logged in there.

Comment: "But WordPress is not allowing me to login from Laravel Sub-Domain." - what have you tried so far? How is it not allowing you exactly?

Comment: In my AuthCrontroller.php I have used this code:

$login_data = array();     
$login_data['user_login'] = $req->email;  
$login_data['user_password'] = $req->password; 
$login_data['remember'] = true; 
   
$user_verify = wp_signon( $login_data, false );
wp_set_current_user($user_verify->ID);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_verify->ID);
$cur = wp_get_current_user();
return redirect('dashboard');

and it was working fine when my wordpress site was [http://example.com] and Laravel site was [http://example.com/laravel]

Comment: Also, if I print variable **$cur** variable in Laravel AuthCrontroller.php then it shows that user is logged in and I can see WordPress user data. But when I try to fetch other data then it is not allowing me. Also when I move to WordPress site then it seems that user is not logged in there.

Comment: I can't read any of that code. Add it to the question in a proper formatted code style.

Comment: @user3574492 Updated question with code. Please check it now

Comment: Are you using some sort of package for this? How are you handling WP and Laravel integration?

Comment: I am just including wp-load.php file to call WordPress functions in Laravel.